# Are these error messages encountered during `vue create` normal?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I ran the vue/cli command below;

```
vue create default_project
```

I could see many modules created under `node_modules` folder and a package.json file was created. It looks normal.

However, I have the following error;

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\biggie\Dropbox\biggieas\Programming\Vue\test_app\default_project\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\biggie\Dropbox\biggieas\Programming\Vue\test_app\default_project\node_modules\.postcss-selector-parser.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\biggie\Dropbox\biggieas\Programming\Vue\test_app\default_project\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser' -> 'C:\Users\biggie\Dropbox\biggieas\Programming\Vue\test_app\default_project\node_modules\.postcss-selector-parser.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\biggie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-13T07_10_18_241Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

Can development work proceed despite these errors since the node modules seem to be successfully downloaded?

I am using node.js v12.16.3 and vue/cli 4.3.1 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

The errors are definitely not ok.

The errors are caused by long pathname. Running the vue-cli command in a folder with shorter pathname will cause the errors to disappear.